# Как удалить </td> и невидимый перенос, чтобы получилась одна строка? PHP

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Здравствуйте =) Вопрос может простой, но я правда не могу удалить все  и "невидимые" переносы, чтобы эти столбцы в исходном коде записались как одна строка.

```
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
```

У меня таблица сначала парсится, потом удаляю в ней все пробелы.
Пробовала так:

```
$table = pq($doc)->find('table > tr > td');
$a = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $table);
$new_table = str_replace("</td>","", $a);
```

Но ничего не происходит. Это мешает мне в дальнейшей работе с массивом -.-

Comment: Если задать одинаковый вопрос два раза лучше ответ врятли получитья.  ;)

Comment: Однако вопрос другой =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправляем значения в массиве:

```
<?php
    function clean($str) {
        // Or any other cleanup...
        return str_replace("</td>","", $str);
    }

    $arr = ['1</td>', '2', '3', '</td>4'];

    var_dump(array_map("clean", $arr));
```

Парсим таблицы через simplexml (задача целкиком)

```
<?php


$str = <<<STR
<body>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>221</td>
        <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>331</td>
        <td>332</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>112</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>221</td>
        <td>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>331</td>
        <td>332</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
STR;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$tables = $xml->xpath('*/table');

$allData = [];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $tableData = [];
    $trs = $table->xpath('tr');
    foreach ($trs as $tr) {
        $trData = [];
        $tds = $tr->xpath('td');
        foreach ($tds as $td) {
            $trData[] = (string) $td;
        }
        $tableData[] = $trData;
    }
    $allData[] = $tableData;
}

var_dump($allData); die();
```

Comment: огромное спасибо =)